# Create image & text grid with responsive css background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

This onlineshop page displays products in rows with 4 elements and displays the product image, title and price. After switching from using `<img>` to a `<div>` with `background-image` (for implementing `background-blend-mode`) I struggle with the responsive display of the product image and height of the box-element.

The gird uses jquery, bootstrap and matchHeight.js

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
        <a href="http://xd.klomfar.at/produkt/papierkorb-waeschekorb-weiss-ohne-deckel/" class="prod-box" data-mh="mh" style="height: 364px;">
             <div class="prod-img-nest">
                 <div class="prod-img" style="background-image: url(''),
url('http://xd.klomfar.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/papierkorb-weiß-klomfar-1-370x370.jpg');   background-blend-mode: multiply; background-size: 100%, contain; background-position: center center;">
                 </div>
                 <!-- OLD IMAGE solution <img src="http://xd.klomfar.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/papierkorb-weiß-klomfar-1-370x370.jpg" class="attachment-product-thumb-size size-product-thumb-size wp-post-image wp-post-image" />-->
                <div class="name">Papierkorb / Wäschekorb</div>
                <div class="desc">
                    Edelstahl Weiß matt, in zwei Größen
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">24,00 <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span> – <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">34,00 <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span> EUR</strong>
                 </div>
              </div>                
        </a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/thaFlow/pen/RwPBGyG

So how do I get the content into the `<div>` and make sure the image is responsive and doesnt repeat or have overflow?

Comment: The codepen does exactly whats expected, when i change screen size the background , all stays in place and within the divs, no overflow  so whats the problem?

Comment: Add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to `.prod-box .prod-img` css.

Comment: @Grumpy please check again with added `margin-bottom`
@RobMoll damn... overlooked that one :)

Comment: checkout screenshot [link](https://imgur.com/a/VHN28lb). first it loads the image quite small so the matchHeight.js probably takes this height as limit, but after a finishing loading, the image enlarges and pushes the text outside the element.